# Adding a string variable inside an html code

Tags: javascript, html

i have an html block that contains few buttons and one text input. The placeholder of this text input should be changed in the different situations. 
Therefore i add a string variable. Then i put the html inside in another string variable:

```
var dataType;

var htmlBlock = `<div class="icon negative big toleft" id="cancel-btn"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></div>
<div class="icon add big toleft"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></div>
<input type="text" class="contact-input" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" maxlength="50" name="my-contact-phone" data-name="Name" placeholder=${dataType}>`
```

as you can see, in the last line of html code, i added ${dataType} in the placeholder part.

then i use it with these codes:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('.js-phone'))
{
  dataType = "Add your number "
  this.html = this.phone.html();
  this.phone.html(
    htmlBlock
  )
};
```

after compiling, in the text input placeholder, this text appears: undefined

Could anyone help me that how i can do it?
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: to use this type of string concatenation, use the curly braces for your variable ... `${dataType}` (not the regular, rounded parentheses)

Comment: @Doug thank you so much for your help. I did it, and now it shows undefined in the placeholder

Comment: Can you provide more of your JavaScript? Maybe link to a JSFiddle or something?

Comment: @Doug I just found out what the problem comes from. If i add a value in dataType variable in the first line, everything will be fine. But i need this variable get a value inside the if condition.

Comment: instead of using htmlBlock as a variable, you can turn it into a function that returns the html data `function htmlBlock( dataType ){ return ...; }` and then when you call it in `this.phone.html()` you can pass the dataType variable and get the updated result

Comment: @Doug can i ask you to write the code that you said to me? i am not sure that i understand it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, your `dataType` variable should be defined **before** you will use that variable in your string literal (template):

```
var dataType = 'HELLO';
var htmlBlock = `<div class="icon negative big toleft" id="cancel-btn"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></div>
<div class="icon add big toleft"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></div>
<input type="text" class="contact-input" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" maxlength="50" name="my-contact-phone" data-name="Name" placeholder="${dataType}">`;

console.log(htmlBlock);
```

---

**UPDATED**:

in this case you could do:

```
var getHtmlBlock = function(dataType) {
    return `<div class="icon negative big toleft" id="cancel-btn"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></div><div class="icon add big toleft"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></div><input type="text" class="contact-input" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" maxlength="50" name="my-contact-phone" data-name="Name" placeholder="${dataType}">`;
};

var myDataType =  getHtmlBlock('Add your number');
console.log(myDataType); // replaced string with argument value;
```

Put your string into function, and replace `${dataType}` by passing as argument.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but i really need this variable get a value in the if condition. Not before it

Answer (score 1):

Your placeholder needs to be wrapped in double quotes "". If you need $(dataType) to place the value in as a placeholder (I'm assuming as jQuery value) you'll need to concatenate the string like this:

```
placeholder="' + dataType + '"
```

Don't miss the single quotes between the double quotes you're concatenating.
It looks like you're trying to both get and set a value using jquery. It's better to get the value of an object, e.g. $(myVal).val(), then use the variable to set it into your other code.

Comment: @donCarlosll Thank you very much, it works now, but the problem is, it's show undefined now.  I just found out what the problem comes from. If i add a value in dataType variable in the first line, everything will be fine. But i need this variable get a value inside the if condition

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your htmlBlock variable into a function that receives an argument "dataType" and returns the html data string that you'd like.

This is a simplified version of your JavaScript:

- tests IF there is an element with the className 'js-phone'
- triggers a window prompt to ask the user for information (a phone number)
- then that info is saved to a variable 'dataType'
- that variable is passed into the htmlBlock function
- which in turn, returns the html data string with the new value

```js
function htmlBlock( dataType ){
  // the important keyword here is "return" ...
  // when this function is called, it will give back
  // (or return) the html string described here
  return `<div class="icon negative big toleft" id="cancel-btn"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></div>
<div class="icon add big toleft"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></div>
<input type="text" class="contact-input" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" maxlength="50" name="my-contact-phone" data-name="Name" placeholder="${dataType}">`;
}

if (document.getElementsByClassName('js-phone')){
  // window.prompt will return the value put in by the 
  // user -- this assigns that returned value to a 
  // variable named dataType
  var dataType = window.prompt('What is your phone number?');
  // this is just grabbing the first element with the
  // 'js-phone' class and adding the html data from
  // the htmlBlock() function
  document.getElementsByClassName('js-phone')[0].innerHTML = htmlBlock( dataType );
  // the key here is the call to htmlBlock( dataType )
  // we got dataType from the prompt
  // and the htmlBlock is our function written above.
};
```

```html
<div class="js-phone"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your string before referencing other JavaScript variables. Then concatenate the strings with the '+' operator and finish the tag. For example:

```
var htmlBlock = '...<input type="text" class="contact-input" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" maxlength="50" name="my-contact-phone" data-name="Name" placeholder=' + dataType + '>';
```

Anything in the quotes will be treated as just characters, not program code.